# VPN client does all TCP traffic get encrypted

Tags: vpn

If I am using a VPN agent, like PIA, I know my http traffic is encrypted, but what about all the other services and applications on the computer that talk to the Internet; such as Windows update, POP3 Outlook, IM, Skype, Adobe services, etc.

Comment: Yes; All traffic on a VPN is encrypted

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

All traffic within the VPN is encrypted, regardless of type.

As long as the VPN encrypts data at all, that is.